# How to link a href with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to have an ID being linked with the clicked result from my output but I want java script to get the link to avoid calling another page. My old way of coding is like this, I have cut the other info.

```
$id=$row["IndexNo"];
echo '
    <tr>
    <td>'. $row["IndexNo"] . '</td>
    <td>'. $row["SurName"] . '</td>
    <td>'. $row["FirstName"] .'</td>
    <td><a href="update.php?IndexNo='. $id . '">view</a></td>
    </tr>';
```

this way the page update.php is loaded with a URL:.../update.php?IndexNo=1. I want to avoid this page load by introducing java script like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#update").click(function(){
        $("#content").load("update.php");
    });
});
```

the thing is I don't seem to know how to  link the two on click of what I should put in the href but at the same time call the ID to only call a distinct result for that selected IndexNo.

Comment: Your question is not clear?please try to write what you want point wise?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want like this :-

```
<td><a class= 'update' href="update.php?IndexNo='. $id . '">view</a></td>
```

so when click on a update link  reqeust goes to update.php?IndexNo={$id} and content will load in #content element of page, and page will not refresh

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(document).on('click', '.update',function(){
            $("#content").load($(this).attr('href'));
            return false;  // __prevent from default action            

     });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: that still didn't work, it was overpowered and the page update.php?IndexNo=1 loaded. I also had to put double quotes on the class="update" to escape a syntax error. Lets try more

Comment: Tiger, It worked my guy I was miss matching the class name. I standardized the update in php and js. Cheers

Comment: I now have another problem, how do I get the IndexNo using the $_get method like: $IndexNo = $_GET['IndexNo']; as the URL is hidden? I want to use this to complete my query like: $sql = "SELECT * FROM student_information WHERE IndexNo='$IndexNo'";

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you don't want to redirect the page while clicking on the anchor tag. Is that ? Then, please replace your code with any one of below set:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#update").click(function(){
        $("#content").load("update.php");
        return false;
    });
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#update").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#content").load("update.php");
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: I now have another problem, how do I get the IndexNo using the $_get method like: $IndexNo = $_GET['IndexNo']; as the URL is hidden? I want to use this to complete my query like: $sql = "SELECT * FROM student_information WHERE IndexNo='$IndexNo'";

Answer (score 0):

if you want to update the current data without refreshing the current page you need to use ajax.With ajax you can send the data(id) to another page with out refreshing.

Comment: //ignore previous comment
$id=$row["IndexNo"];
echo '
    <tr>
    <td>'. $row["IndexNo"] . '</td>
    <td>'. $row["SurName"] . '</td>
    <td>'. $row["FirstName"] .'</td>
    <td><button id="redirect" onclick="hai('<?php print $id; ?>')">view</button></td>
    </tr>';


 function hai(id){
 
$.ajax({
          
          url: "update.php",
          type: 'POST',
          data: {
              
             "id":id
              
          },
          success: function (data) {
                        
                alert(data);
             // display result  
    
        }
    })
}

Comment: I now have another problem, how do I get the IndexNo using the $_get method like: $IndexNo = $_GET['IndexNo']; as the URL is hidden? I want to use this to complete my query like: $sql = "SELECT * FROM student_information WHERE IndexNo='$IndexNo'";

Answer (score 0):

```
$id=$row["IndexNo"];
echo '
    <tr>
    <td>'. $row["IndexNo"] . '</td>
    <td>'. $row["SurName"] . '</td>
    <td>'. $row["FirstName"] .'</td>
    <td><button onclick="hai('<?php print $id; ?>')">view</button></td>
    </tr>';

//ajax code
function hai(id)
{ 
    $.ajax({ 
    url: "update.php", 
    type: 'POST', 
    data: { 
    "id":id 
    }, 
    success: function (data) 
    { 
    alert(data); 
        // display result 
    } 
    }) 
} 

//on updat.php page 

$indexNo=$_POST['id'];
```

Comment: follow my other question for a detailed outline http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29389005/how-to-get-a-value-from-a-hidden-url